# PIC32CX register names not in header?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplab, pic32

I'm trying to hack away using a PIC32CX BZ2. Since there's no code completion for some weird reason in MPLAB, I'm kinda forced to know the register names, or whatever is set declared in the header files. If they matched with the documentation and I could use TRISA and so on it would be fine. But there's only GPIOB_REGS->GPIO_TRIS and other things like that - that is completely unque. And again, without type ahead, I have to dig for these in the header files. That can't be the plan from Microchip, right? Is there any way to use normal register names? Thanks!

EDIT:
Ok, just to clarify: This is a WBZ451 with a PIC32CX BZ2 on board. I'm using MPLAB, the correct compiler (XC32) is installed and works fine (compiles programs that work) and the correct device is selected. See screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you select the correct controller in your IDE you only had to include `xc.h`. Every registername should be defined now.

Comment: I have selected the correct controller, and the xc.h is already included when I create a c file. This is how I have things like GPIOB_REGS->GPIO_TRIS defined. Do I have to set anything for the compiler (as I had to do for the XC8 compiler)?

Comment: I would expect some documentation of the provided libraries and header files. What does _that_ say?

Comment: xc8 is for 8 Bit controller and PIC32CX is a 32 Bit controller. so 1. select correct controller in your project, 2. select xc32 compiler, 3. include `xc.h`

Comment: @Mike, I'm not saying that I have tried to program a PIC32CX with the xc8 compiler. I'm saying that when one would simply download MPLAB and the xc8 compiler, that wouldn't work out of the box with a 8 bit controller either. None of the registers are recognised, the include path must be set for the compiler.
I expect a similar trick for the WBZ451 and the xc32 compiler too.

Comment: @thebusybee, I could not find any documentation for the libraries. There's docu for the controller, that lists the register names. Then there is the IDE (MPLAB, their own IDE). I create a project selecting the controller I have, the include for xc.h is there. Further controller specific includes are in there (wbz451.h). Still, TRISA for example is not defined. ??

Comment: If you select a 8-bit controller, select xc8 compiler, include `xc.h`everything should work fine. At least for me.

Comment: The complete documentation is installed with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The PIC32CX is an ARM based 32 bit controller and the xc8 compiler is a compiler for 8-bit microchip controller.
If you want to work with the PIC32CX yout had install and select a suitable compiler:

- xc32 compiler or
- ARM 32-bit GNU toolchain

If you want to work with an 8-bit microchip controller, the xc8 compiler is a good choice to start.
You can do this settings in your procect properties.
And never forget:

```
#include <xc.h>
```

The handling of the configuration register is total different in the microchip controller with MIPS core to the one with an ARM core:

MIPS: `ASNSELA = 0x0000;`

ARM: `GPIOA_REGS->GPIO_ANSEL = 0x0000;`

Comment: We are talking about a 32 bit controller. Can you please share a screenshot showing the usage of the TRISA regster using a PIC32CX BZ2 processor! Because I'm convinced that the headers so not define the register names according to the documentation.

Comment: For a PIC32MX for example the p32mx230f064b.h lines 4647 and under define TRISA, and it all works fine. For the PIC32CX processors this is NOT the case. This is what I would like to establish first as true, then I could continue with further questions.

Comment: I've never worked with the PIC32CX, but this one is total different to the MX controller, which is MIPS based. The PIC32CX is an ARM based controllter. So you had to look into the documentation how to configure the IO pins.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I'm glad that there's somebody who answers at all. Having said that, the question is about the PIC32CX and if you have never worked with that you probably can't answer the question. What you could do if you have felt that your environment is set up properly, is to create a project using the said controller and see if you can compile the code in my question.